# Regex to get first word after third slash but before minus symbol

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is one of the URL's I have to deal with ...

```
https://www.some-domain.de/city/123/street-firstname-lastname
```

I need to get the **street** using JS. The domain stays the same, the city stays the same but the number **123** can vary.

I managed to get some other values so far but completely lost on how to get the street. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please share your code with us.

Comment: Split on slash and get the wanted element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using some existing library ([like this?](https://dmitripavlutin.com/parse-url-javascript/)) to parse the url and isolate the *path*. Then split on `'/'` to get path segments (or maybe the url-parser you use will have an option for this). Once you have the single path segment you want, you could split on `'-'`, or use a regex, whichever.

The advantage of this is not just that you won't have to write a large complex regex yourself, it'll also free a lot of your assumptions about the input data and give a more reliable solution.

Comment: That did the trick. I was thinking to complex. I just picked the last slash and split it up and used everything before the minus "-".

Answer (score 0):

```
var citynumber = document.location.href.split('/')[4];

var address = document.location.href.split('/')[5];
var street= address.split('-')[0]
```

Found it with the help of @ShapeOfMatter. I just picked everything after the last slash, tne split it up using "-" this time and not "/" and then picked the first word. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex validates the url-pattern and captures the street name ...

[`/^https*:\/\/(?:[^\/]+\/){3}([^-]+)/`](https://regex101.com/r/EppN9L/1)

It reads ...

- `^https*:\/\/` ... match from the beginning either of the protocols `http://` or `https://`
- `(?:[^\/]+\/){3}` ... match the following pattern ...

  - `[^\/]+\/` ... a sequence of any characters that are not a slash terminated/followed by a slash.
  - do not capture this group ... `(?: ... )`
  - but the pattern has to be repeated exactly 3 times ... `{3}`.
- `([^-]+)` ... capture a sequence of any characters that are not a minus/dash, which is the *street name*.

```js
const regXCaptureStreet = (/^https*:\/\/(?:[^\/]+\/){3}([^-]+)/gm);

const sampleText =
`https://some-domain.de/city/123/street-firstname-lastname
//foo/bar/baz/biz/
http://example.org/the-city/987654/mystreetname-myfirstname-mylastname
//foo/bar/baz/biz/
https://some-domain.de/city/123/streetname-firstname-lastname
//foo/bar/baz/biz/
http://example.org/the-city/987654/nameofstreet-myfirstname-mylastname`;

console.log(
  [...sampleText.matchAll(regXCaptureStreet)].map(result => result[1])
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```